# Creating a custom login instead of using the original login box

Tags: php, javascript, html, objective-c, titanium

Lets say there is a php website that has a login boxes (password,username), can you create a login box in different page of your own that when you enter your login information it will let you log to that website? I mean is it possible? and using what language?

If anyone wants a link of the website I would be glad to post it. It is my university website actually.

This may help:

```
<b>User Name:</b></span></td>
                            <td width="60%"><span class="text10">
                            <script language="JavaScript1.2">
                      document.writeln("<input class=\"textform\" type=\"text\" name=\"user\" size=\"" + size + "\" tabindex=1 onFocus=\"hadFocus(true);\">");
                      </script>
```

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean creating a login form so that you can gain access to an administration back end for example?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the university site's login HTML into your page (everything in the <form> element, including the <form> element itself) and change the action so that it's fully qualified (i.e. if the action was /login.php change it to http://myuniversity.edu/login.php).

Then, you can mess around with the HTML and modify it however you like. The important things are that any inputs, selects, and textareas have the same name as they do on the university login form, and that the action is a full URL.

Comment: As the long the uni's site doesn't check referers and/or insert anti-spam measures into the form, this'd work.

Comment: @Marc B: if you find a university that does that let me know the name of it so that I can go get another degree there. That's a school I'm willing to invest in :)

Comment: Thanks Jordan and Marc. This is what I actually did in the first place. But I love asking in SOF and I'm sure I will find some lovely idea here. Okay how about creating a form in an iPhone app? is it still possible? without using an offline page in the app it self.

Comment: I read this answer before the question and I thought you were supporting him in some password scam XD

Comment: LOL Luke Landwalker.  Well the reason I asked this question because my university login page has some issues using iPhone or any iDevice. So, I thought playing around and find a solution.

Comment: @Mohammad: you should be able to do the same thing from an iphone app. You will simply post an HTTP request with the name/value pairs to the login page and it should work. It looks like the page is doing some "fancy" javascript which could honestly just be left out, since it's only sizing the text box. And yes @Luke Landwalker I was sort of hoping this was a password scam, but sadly it wasn't :(

Comment: Can you still be able to this even if the university is using https? Thanks again guys. I learned a lot from SOF.

Comment: @Mohammad I'm honestly not sure. Have you tried it and it's not working?

Comment: I'll try it today after finishing classes and see.  Thanks Jordan :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to just view the code of the original login page, copy the HTML for the form, and try pasting that into your page.